# Create objects Type T in .Net Core

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

I'm creating a web app in .net core and I'm trying to create a generic way to set and get "objects" from Session. The part of setting and getting I can do, my only problem is that I want to initialize the object if it doesn't exists on the session. The error that I get is that 'T' must be a non-abstract type with a public parameterless constructor in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'SessionExtensions.CreateObject()
Can someone help me? 
Thanks in the advance :)
PS: here is my code:

```
public static class SessionExtensions
{
    public static void Set<T>(this ISession session, string key, T value)
    {
        session.SetString(key, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value));
    }

    public static T Get<T>(this ISession session, string key)
    {
        var value = session.GetString(key);
        return value == null ? CreateObject<T>() :
                              JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(value);
    }

    public static T CreateObject<T>() where T : new()
    {
        return new T();
    }
}
```

Comment: The compiler is rather clear, you can use a type which is an abstract class, an interface or a class without a parameterless constructor inside your `Set<T>` or `Get<T>` methods because those methods do not restricts `T` as `new()`, while `CreateObjects` does. Can you be more clear on what you are asking?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your comment, so what is your advice to create the object if he is null in this generic way? :)

Comment: Is there a *specific* reason why you need to create a new object if it does not exists in the session? What about complex types with parameters inside the constructor? Why can't you handle missing keys from the calling code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `CreateObject<T>` method restricts `T` to a type with a parameterless constructor (and, of course, not abstract). For this reason you cannot use this method with a *less-restricted* `T` like in your `Get<T>` or `Set<T>`.

Either add `new()` constraint to your `Get<T>` method or do not use `CreateObject<T>` and return `default(T)` from your `Get<T>` method, which will return `null` for reference types and the default value for value types.

In your scenario I believe is not necessary at all to return a new object when the key is missing from the session dictionary, it is more reasonable to return the default for that type and handle a *cache-miss* from the caller:

```
public static class SessionExtensions
{
    public static void Set<T>(this ISession session, string key, T value)
    {
        session.SetString(key, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value));
    }

    public static T Get<T>(this ISession session, string key)
    {
        var value = session.GetString(key);
        return value == null ? default(T) :
                              JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(value);
    }
}
```

Calling code:

```
var obj = session.Get<MyClass>("myKey") ?? new MyClass();
```

Comment: Thank you @Frederico Dipuma, was really this i was looking for. Thank you for your help :)